# golang remote imports fail

Tags: import, go

I just install golang with homebrew and I am having trouble importing remote packages.

when I try to instal demo.go which contains

```
import "github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache"
```

I get the following error

```
$ go install
demo.go:3:8: cannot find package "github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache" in any of:
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4/libexec/src/github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache (from $GOROOT)
/Users/white/go/src/github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache (from $GOPATH)
```

To my untrained eyes it looks like it is just looking locally on my GOPATH.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "remote import". All imports are local, they just happen to use their url for convenience.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That means you need to get it first:

```
go get github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache
```

That is what the [`bradfitz/gomemcache`](https://github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache) recommends.

Comment: Is that true of all remote imports?  It's not just the memcache package that gives me this error.

Comment: @honkskillet the import of golang packages would not involve a go get, since they are in your `$GOROOT`. The rest would involve a `go get`.

Comment: i had to set GOPATH first

Comment: @donbright Unless you are using Go 1.8: GOPATH is set for you: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17262

Answer (score 5):

Your untrained eyes are not fooling you: the go compiler will only look for code that is stored locally.

The `go get` tool, however, can be used to fetch code that is stored in a remote repository and copy it over locally. So, if you type:

`go get github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache`

you will have a copy of the code in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache`

Notice that `github.com/bradfitz/gomemcahce/memcache` is actually a local directory path, so you use `import "github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache"` to import it in your code. It just happens to also be the name of a remote repository that the `go get` tool knows how to fetch.